# How to add a Jar file to a Cordova plugin for Android without compiling it into the APK

Tags: android, cordova, jar, cordova-plugins

I am creating a Cordova plugin and want to link against an existing jar.  All the documentation and help for this says to add jars to the plugin's 'libs' folder which works fine if you want to include the JAR into the final APK but I want to include it as a **runtime dependency only**.

I can do this in Android Studio or eclipse by adding the JAR as a dependency and selecting the Scope as 'Provided' but that option would not be open to anybody who wanted to build an app using my plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the latest version of the Cordova CLI I discovered (version 5.0).  As long as you're building using gradle you can include the jar file into your project (say under /lib)

```
<source-file src="myjar.jar" target-dir="lib" />
```

then include an extras.gradle file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    provided files('lib/myjar.jar')
}
```

And add a reference in the plugin.xml

```
<framework src="src/android/extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>
```

Comment: This is long after the fact, but could you explain where the <source-file> tag should go? Is that in plugin.xml?

Comment: <source-file> goes in Plugin.xml, please see here: https://github.com/darryncampbell/EnterpriseBarcodePoC/blob/master/plugin.xml